# How to look up files (.txt) in a folder, import delimited data from file into excel, then move txt file to archive?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a folder that will be populated by files with common characters but with a single digit variance, i.e. Test 34, or Test 40. The folder can be empty or contain 50 files.

I'm trying to write code that can:

1. go to folder check if folfer is empty, if not
2. take each text file and import space delimited data into excel (ideally based on date of file modification in folder - haven't gotten that far yet.)
3. Move files to archive folder (may cause me issues if file name already exists in archive)
4. if folder empty, exit/end sub

I've tried various methods, however my VBA knowledge isn't great. Below is a version of my code that has been spliced with various code from stackoverflow

```
Sub ImportFiles()
Dim eRow As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim rowNumber As String
Dim outputSheet As String
Dim sheetName As String
Dim folder As String
Dim strPath As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim fCount As Long

folder = "U:\Projects\Raw data\"
outputSheet = "Dataset"

    fCount = UBound(Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & folder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")) + 1

    'MsgBox Format(fCount, "#,00") & " files were found."



    If Dir(folder & "*.*") = "" Then
        MsgBox "The folder doesn't contain (visible) files"
        MsgBox "Bye Bye!!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'MsgBox "The folder does contain (visible) files"

        For i = 0 To 11
            fileName = folder & "Test" & i & ".txt"
                'If Dir(fileName) = "" Then     
            eRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            With Sheets(outputSheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" + fileName, Destination:=Sheets(outputSheet).Range("$A$" + eRow))
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
                .TextFilePlatform = 850
                .TextFileStartRow = 1
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

            End With

                    Dim wb_conection As WorkbookConnection
                    For Each wb_Connection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
                    If InStr(fileName, wb_Connection.Name) > 0 Then
                    wb_Connection.Delete
                    End If
                    Next wb_Connection                
        Next i    
    End If

    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't got time for a full answer at the moment, but you might want to do some research on FileSystemObject. That may well get you closer to what you want to do.

Comment: Can you elaborate what your code currently does and where it fails or where you have difficulties. It is unclear to me what you're asking

Comment: Yes, in addition to @Dave, you can use the `.files` collection and on each `.file` look at the `.type` or the extension.  There is also a way with ADO to I believe that may help

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Currently the code iterates through file names starting with ones that contain "0" in the name, i.e. "Test0", this is the immediate issue in that once it does not detect this file, I get a compiler error when in reality I want it to move to the next iteration of i. I'ld prefer not to use this method since if the folder contains only the following file; "Test55" the code will have to iterate 54 times until the file is matched. I hope this makes sence.